# Trying to get a fixed value in Group by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to calculate a weighted score for each line here.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
```

```
index   firm    sales  burgers

0   McDonalds   100 2

1   McDonalds   100 1

2   McDonalds   100 3

3   McDonalds   100 2

4   McDonalds   100 4

5   Burger King 105 1

6   Burger King 105 1

7   Burger King 105 1

8   Burger King 105 1

9   Burger King 105 3

10  Burger King 105 4

11  Burger King 105 4
```

[Output from df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lYBb.png)

```
df[weighted score] = df[Total Sales] * df[total sales / sum(firm name total sales)] # I know this second part is wrong but trying to illustrate what I am going for
```

What I want is to have a fixed denominator for each Firm (mcdonalds, Burger King). So for Mcdonalds, it would be the sum of all the sales (500). this would then be divided by total sales for that line (so 100/500 for each, which would be a score of .2 for each line in the new column.

I will then aggregate by firm using groupby.

I want a fixed value denominator i can use in each line item to calculate a weighted average

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: better put example data as text (as DataFrame) so we could simply copy and use it. And show expected result for these example.

Comment: if you want to work with every firm separatelly then maybe you should use `group_by("Firm")` and later work with every group.

Comment: @furas then how do I get the 500 stored as a value? How do I sum the sales by firm and store as a value? Sorry my question was messy I am still learning how to do this

Comment: I will repeate: it would be simpler if you would put example data as text (as DataFrame) - and then we can use it to show solution.

Comment: probably `df.group_by("Firm")["Total Sales"].sum()` should gives you sum for all firms at once.

Comment: @furas I just tried to fix. so do you mean doing like:

mcdonalds_sales = df.group_by('McDonalds")["Sales"].sum()

and 

BK_sales = df.group_by('BK")["Sales"].sum()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby('firm')` to make calculation for every firm separatelly.

In group you can use aggregation's functions like `sum()`,`min()`,`max()`,`mean()`, etc. (which give single value for every group) or use `apply()` to calculate new values for new columns.

This runs function for every group separatelly and calculate percentage value for clumns `salese` using `column / column.sum()`

```
df['percent'] = df.groupby("firm")['sales'].apply(lambda col: col/col.sum())
```

or longer

```
def my_function(col):
    return col/col.sum()

df['percent'] = df.groupby("firm")['sales'].apply(my_function)
```

---

Minimal working code.

I used `io` only to simulate file in memory - so everyone can simply copy and run example. But you should read data from real file.

I `BurgerKing` I removed space to simpler parse example data (because there are no `,` between columns so I used space(s) as separator)

```
text = '''index   firm    sales  burgers
0   McDonalds   100 2
1   McDonalds   100 1
2   McDonalds   100 3
3   McDonalds   100 2
4   McDonalds   100 4
5   BurgerKing 105 1
6   BurgerKing 105 1
7   BurgerKing 105 1
8   BurgerKing 105 1
9   BurgerKing 105 3
10  BurgerKing 105 4
11  BurgerKing 105 4'''


import pandas as pd
import io

#df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')

print('\n--- before ---\n')
print(df)

#print(df.groupby("firm")['sales'].sum())


df['percent'] = df.groupby("firm")['sales'].apply(lambda column: column/column.sum())

print('\n--- after ---\n')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
--- before ---

    index        firm  sales  burgers
0       0   McDonalds    100        2
1       1   McDonalds    100        1
2       2   McDonalds    100        3
3       3   McDonalds    100        2
4       4   McDonalds    100        4
5       5  BurgerKing    105        1
6       6  BurgerKing    105        1
7       7  BurgerKing    105        1
8       8  BurgerKing    105        1
9       9  BurgerKing    105        3
10     10  BurgerKing    105        4
11     11  BurgerKing    105        4

--- after ---

    index        firm  sales  burgers   percent
0       0   McDonalds    100        2  0.200000
1       1   McDonalds    100        1  0.200000
2       2   McDonalds    100        3  0.200000
3       3   McDonalds    100        2  0.200000
4       4   McDonalds    100        4  0.200000
5       5  BurgerKing    105        1  0.142857
6       6  BurgerKing    105        1  0.142857
7       7  BurgerKing    105        1  0.142857
8       8  BurgerKing    105        1  0.142857
9       9  BurgerKing    105        3  0.142857
10     10  BurgerKing    105        4  0.142857
11     11  BurgerKing    105        4  0.142857
```

Comment: what does lambda do here?

Comment: apply needs function's name which it executes on every group - so you can create function `def my_function(column): return column/column.sum()` and run `.apply(my_function)`. Or you can use `lambda` to create this function - and code is shorter.

Comment: I add this function in first part of answer.